# How to navigate to a folder using folder path in Mac?

Tags: macbook

in windows we paste the folder location and enter to navigate to the folder.

in mac, how to do it?

i know a folder path and want to navigate to that folder

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finder has a menu item found under Go ("Go to Folder…") where you can type a full path.

The command+shift+G keyboard shortcut makes it handy to summon. This short cut works in the file open and save dialog as well.